# Getting multiple values from a List box in C# windows form

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a list box that is pulling it's data from a sql table. I have its selection mode set to multisimple.

I have the display member for each item set to the Name field from the sql table and the value member for each item set to the ID field from the sql table.

When I select multiple items from the list, how do I get the multiple values? I am able to get the text of one item by using the listboxname.Text but I don't know how to get each value that has been selected all at once.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1 :** You can use `SelectedIndices` property of the `ListBox` to get the All selected items `Index` values.
then for each selected index you can get the `Value` of the Item.

Try This:

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<String> SelectedItems=new List<String>();
            foreach (int i in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
            {
               SelectedItems.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
            }               
        }
```

Note : List `SelectedItems`  contains all SelectedItems from the `ListBox`

**Method 2:** 
You can use `SelectedItems` property of the `ListBox` to get the All selected item values directly.

Try This:

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<String> SelectedItems=new List<String>();
            foreach (String s in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
               SelectedItems.Add(s);
            }               
        }
```

Note : List `SelectedItems`  contains all SelectedItems from the `ListBox`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SelectedItems` property, the following will get a `List<string>` representing the selected items:

```
var items = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>()
                    .Select(x=>Convert.ToString(x)).ToList();
```

To get the exact values (ID), it depends on the underlying item type. If you use a `DataTable` as `DataSource` for your listBox, the underlying item type is `DataRowView`, so the code to get the values IDs should be:

```
var ids = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>()
                  .Select(row=>row.Row.Field<string>("ID")).ToList();
//suppose the ID field is string
```

If the underlying item type is just a normal class with 2 properties Name and ID, such as call it `Item`, the code is simpler like this:

```
var ids = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<Item>()
                  .Select(item=>item.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: And link to MSDN help of SelectedItems http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx¨